# When I get the total bounds of a shapefile, which are llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon, and urcrnrlat? Need it to use Maptlotlib Basemap

Tags: python, geopandas, extents, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

The goal is to use an ESRI webmap as a basemap beneath a shapefile for a script that visualizes earthquakes in the Philippines. But first, I'm practicing in using Basemap in a separate script.

According to the Basemap documentation, I need to get the following to dictate where the webmap is:

```
For most map projections, the map projection region can either be specified by setting these keywords:
Keyword     Description
llcrnrlon   longitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
llcrnrlat   latitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
urcrnrlon   longitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
urcrnrlat   latitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
```

So, to get the total bounds of the Philippines shapefile from GADM:

```
import geopandas as gpd
prov  = gpd.read_file('Provinces.shp')

In: prov.total_bounds
Out: array([116.9283371 ,   4.58693981, 126.60534668,  21.07014084])
```

To get an ESRI basemap:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'path')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'path'
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

tb = {'llon': 116.9283371, 'llat': 4.58693981, 
      'ulon': 126.60534668, 'ulat': 21.07014084}

map = Basemap(projection="tmerc", ellps='WGS84', epsg='4326',
              llcrnrlon=tb['llon'], llcrnrlat=tb['llat'],
              urcrnrlon=tb['ulon'], urcrnrlat =tb['ulat'],
              lon_0=np.average([116.9283371, 126.60534668]), 
              lat_0=np.average([4.58693981, 21.07014084]))

map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=2000, 
                verbose=True, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

Result is a blank plot

[image]

The code is inspired by this thread: [Using Google Maps image as layer with Matplotlib Basemap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212736/using-google-maps-image-as-layer-with-matplotlib-basemap)

Comment: According to [this](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/index.html#deprecation-notice) *"Basemap is deprecated in favor of the Cartopy project"*, check [`cartopy`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/). Check this thread [Python basemap module impossible to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import) as well.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try Cartopy instead of Basemap.